# First entry keep inserting vie datagrid view in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

all I'm saving data of data grid view in accessdb but problem is everytime first entry keeps inserting when I try to debug data goes properly in cmd.parameters here is my code

```
Public Sub insert_items()
    ds.Clear()
    str = ""

    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cn.Close()
    End If

    DBConfig.conn()
    cn.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into invoice_items([invoice_id],[item_name],[qty],[rate],[item_code])Values(@invoice_id,@item_name,@qty,@rate,@item_code)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoice_id", invoice_id.Text.ToString)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_name", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_code", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


    Next
End Sub
```

here if my datagridview has 5 diffrent entries the first entry will be inserted 5 times instead of all diffrent entries

Comment: Your issue is that your are creating a new set of parameters on every iteration and adding it to the parameter collection.  Since access uses positional params rather than named, it doesn't care you are duplicating them.  Options:  1)Move the Parameter adding outside the loop and update value in each iteration.  2) Clear the Parameter collection on each iteration

Comment: Couple other things to note.  Appears you're using a global DB connection.  This can be troublesome.  Read up on Using, IDisposable and how it applies to DB connections.  Next, using Parameters.AddWithValue() can be problematic and do un-intended type casts.  Much safer to use Parameters.Add("@paramName, DBType).value = ....  You can be very explicit about the Type.  Lastly, TableAdapters do a large amount of all this for you

Comment: Don't use a loop in the first place. Create a `DataTable` and bind it to your grid. Any records added to the grid will be automatically added to the `DataTable`. You can then save the lot with a single call to `Update` on a suitably-configured data adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I cleared parametere in loop for first release will update with data table in next update Thanks alot